# Jquery FadeIn not working in google chrome

Tags: jquery

This code working fine in Firefox but its not working with fade effect in google chrome .Please help me how to solve this problem.. Thanks in advance .

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Fade IN</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.js"</script>
    </head>
    <body id="new" background="../../images/login_1.jpeg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function($) {

      $(document.body).fadeIn(3000);

    })(jQuery);
    </script>

<div id="showcase">
    <br><br>
    <center><h1 style="color:black;">test</h1></center>
      <center><h3 style="color:black;">test</h3>    </center>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your `script` tag is missing a `>` on the opening tag. Chrome has a Javascript Console too, if you're not watching it while loading/working on the page, start there.

Comment: You want the body to fadeIn, but I don't see that it was ever hidden to start with?  You can't fade something in that is already visible.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
(function ($) {
   $(document.body).hide().fadeIn(3000);
})(jQuery);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XqyFa/)